# JSF command button not working within included JSF page

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I'm try to build application with Primefaces 4.0 and JSF 2.2.5. I need to load content dynamically in accordance with choosen menu item.
Here is my main page:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
<title>Hello, world!</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<p:layout fullPage="true">
    <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="15%">
        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton value="List1" action="#{backingBean.setCurrentPage('included.xhtml')}"
                             update=":mypanel_id" process="@this"/><br/>
            <p:commandButton value="List2"/>
        </h:form>
    </p:layoutUnit>
    <p:layoutUnit position="center">
        <p:panel id="mypanel_id">
            <ui:include src="#{backingBean.page}"/>
        </p:panel>
        <p:messages autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" showSummary="true"/>
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
</h:body>
</html>
```

And this is included page:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
<title>Hello,world</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputText value="Included page"/>
    <h:form>
        <ui:repeat value="#{backingBean.items}" var="item">
            <p:fieldset legend="item" toggleable="true">
                <h:outputText value="#{item}"/>
                <ui:param name="it" value="#{item}"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Click" style="margin-left: 50px;"
                                 actionListener="#{backingBean.actionListener}"/>
            </p:fieldset>
        </ui:repeat>
        <p:commandButton value="Test" action="#{backingBean.actionListener}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Command buttons not work. Not with action nor with actionListener. What i'm doing wrong? How to build page with conditionally rendered elements, such as command buttons and fieldsets?

P.S. Forget to say, that my bean have request scope.

Updated:

```java
public class BackingBean {
private List<String> items;
private String currentItem;
private String page;

public BackingBean() {
    items = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public List<String> getItems() {
    if (items.size() == 0) {
        this.fillAndUpdate();
    }
    return items;
}

public void setItems(List<String> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

public void fillAndUpdate() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        items.add("Item " + String.valueOf(i));
    }
}

public String getPage() {
    return page;
}

public void setPage(String page) {
    this.page = page;
}

public void setCurrentPage(String page) {
    this.page = page;
}

public void actionListener() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Test"));
}
```

}

**UPDATED**

Ok. I found the error (if someone interested). Because my bean has request scope, when i click the button in right panel my view was updated, but list of items was updated too and became empty (request scope). Now i keep selected menu in the session bean, and return that number when view rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add `ajax="false"` in your command buttons

Comment: @Egor if it doesn't work update your question and put the code of your  backingBean.

Comment: 1) In the seconde Button list2 you didn't specified the actionListener 2) the primefaces showcase can help you http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/growl.jsf.

Comment: I know about second list2, but issue in the other side of thing. When i click command button on included page (it's included by click on menu) nothing happens.